# Escolher quantas linhas quer mostrar no output

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Estou a tentar colocar uma flag -n para conseguir mostrar no output o numero de linhas pretendidas pelo utilizador, tendo até agora conseguido apenas mostrar o numero de linha ao lado

```
case "$1" in                ## definir o pósprocessador
  -r)  pp="shuf" ;;         # -r    shuffle
  -s)  pp="sort" ;;         # -s    sort
   *)  pp="cat -n"  ;;      # default numera linhas
esac
```

Comment: Explique melhor, eu não consegui intender seu propósito.

Comment: Estou a tentar colocar uma flag que mostre o numero de linhas pretendidas pelo utilizador, por exemplo ./bash.sh -n 5 e com isto no output vao so aparecer 5 linhas ou 5 items

Comment: se quiser mostrar as 5 primeiras use o comando `head -n5` se for as últimas 5 use o `tail -n5`. Seria isso?

Answer (score 0):

Com base no seu raciocínio, segue *script* modificado:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    -r) shuf "$2" ;;
    -s) sort "$2" ;;
    *) cat -n "$1" ;;
esac
```

Assumindo que você tenha um arquivo de entrada chamado `frutas.txt` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Banana
Laranja
Melancia
Limão
Maracujá
Maçã
Uva
Goiaba
Tangerina
Pêssego
```

**1)** Embaralhando as linhas do arquivo de entrada:

```
$ ./processador.sh -r frutas.txt
Melancia
Maçã
Pêssego
Maracujá
Goiaba
Banana
Tangerina
Uva
Laranja
Limão
```

**2)** Ordenando as linhas do arquivo de entrada:

```
$ ./processador.sh -s frutas.txt
Banana
Goiaba
Laranja
Limão
Maçã
Maracujá
Melancia
Pêssego
Tangerina
Uva
```

**3)** Exibindo as linhas enumeradas contidas no arquivo de entrada:

```
$ ./processador.sh frutas.txt
     1  Banana
     2  Laranja
     3  Melancia
     4  Limão
     5  Maracujá
     6  Maçã
     7  Uva
     8  Goiaba
     9  Tangerina
    10  Pêssego
```